# How to disable hibernation on debian7?

Tags: debian, hibernate

I DON'T want my bebian into the hibernation status forever,how to disable hibernation on debian7?There is no /etc/default/acpi-support  file on debian7.

[image]

An other error occur when to connect to vps_ip  with ssh  root@vps_ip to sudoedit the file .

sudoedit   /etc/pm/sleep.d/000no-hibernate
sudoedit: unable to write to /etc/pm/sleep.d/000no-hibernate: No such file or directory
sudoedit: contents of edit session left in /var/tmp/000no-hibernate.XXaG8kTt

Comment: Check out this post, it might be of use: https://wiki.debian.org/Hibernation

Answer (score 1):

If you hibernate via *pm-utils*, you can create `/etc/pm/sleep.d/000no-hibernate` with the following content (as root):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" = "hibernate" ]; then
    echo "I disabled hibernation for whatever reason"
    exit 1
fi
```

Don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x`.
You can read more about this hook mechanism in the pm-utils documentation (`/usr/share/doc/pm-utils/README`).

Comment: AN error occur when to input  ':wq' ,why can't save the file    /etc/pm/sleep.d/000no-hibernate ?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, you have to do all this (the file creation and the `chmod`) with superuser privileges (ie. as root). For example, use `sudoedit` instead of plain `vim` (it will run `vim` if that's your highest ranking editor alternative) and$ sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/000no-hibernate

Comment: An other error occur when to connect to vps_ip with ssh root@vps_ip to sudoedit the file .

Comment: sudoedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/000no-hibernate
sudoedit: unable to write to /etc/pm/sleep.d/000no-hibernate: No such file or directory

Comment: sudoedit: contents of edit session left in /var/tmp/000no-hibernate.XXaG8kTt

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, have you got the _pm-utils_ package installed? How do you hibernate your computer? Also, if you use a root terminal, you needn't use `sudo` or `sudoedit`, those are for temporary root access from unprivileged accounts (and require some configuration for that).

Answer (score 1):

Disable suspend and hibernation
For systems which should never attempt any type of suspension, these targets can be disabled at the systemd level with the following:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

To re-enable hibernate and suspend use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

If you just want to prevent suspending when the lid is closed you can set the following options in /etc/systemd/logind.conf:

```
[Login]
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

Then run systemctl restart `systemd-logind.service` or reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works but I found this on https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend for Debian 8 (Jessi):

Use this:
`sudo systemctl mask hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`